# How can I send Newsletter in HTML format?

Tags: emails

I have  installed the following modules simplenews, mailsystem, html mail to send HTML news letter from a Drupal 7 site. Right now, I am just able to send plain text email from send test option. How can I send an HTML email from my site? How can I send a newsletter to registered emails of my site?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at Mime Mail http://drupal.org/project/mimemail, I have already used it to enable HTML in emails but I have not yet used it with a newsletter module.

Comment: @MikaA. is correct, you have to mix mimemail with simplenews and then you can send HTML emails.

Comment: @MikaA. Please post it as an answer so that we can keep the Q/A format.

Comment: ok @NikhilM, just wasn't sure of my answer first, but will be posting it now!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Mime mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) along with your newsletter module to enable HTML in your emails. This module will work on the message mime so it should work with almost any mail module